# Connecting to remote linux web server with off-premise wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ssh, browser, firewall

I have a VM running linux. I use it to host an internal website (say.. secretsite.ss.com:8000). In linux, I have added a firewall rule allowing access to the vm from my laptop's ip. Thus, I am able to access the site. This works fine using my company's wifi connection.

Using my own wifi connection however does not allow the site to load on my laptop, despite adding a new firewall rule for my computer's ip using an alternate wifi. I can still ssh into the server and run scripts, but actually accessing the site via browser (i.e. Chrome) does not render.

What is causing this? How can I get around this blockage?

Comment: I'm not completely certain. I connect via `Putty`. In the putty login screen, I checked each menu and did not see anything saying `bridged`. I have a rudimentary knowledge of wireless networking.

Comment: Is DHCP enabled? Try to set up a static IP.

Comment: Guess: There's NAT involved somewhere in your "own wifi connection", so the firewall doesn't see your laptop's IP address, but the address of the NAT router. Verification: Trace what arrives at the firewill, with wireshark, tcpdump, or firewall logging.

Comment: No one can answer this definitively without more information. You can use an SSH/so proxy to work around it, but the correct solution is to fix your routing and firewalls.

Comment: I reconnected to "my wifi" several times and ran `ifconfig` each time on the VM. It yielded the same internet address each time. Does that mean DHCP is disabled (i.e. IP is static)?